# Override windows gem version deploying to Openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, openshift

I'm attempting to deploy a Rails app which I have developed on Windows, to Openshift. However, the bundle is not complete, because `Gemfile.lock` contains lines like:

```
pg (0.17.0-x86-mingw32)
```

which therefore don't get installed on the Linux instance at Openshift.

Knowing that Heroku works around this by detecting a Windows Gemfile.lock and removing it, I have tried adding a `.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build script doing either

```
rm Gemfile.lock
```

or

```
sed -i /mingw32/d Gemfile.lock
```

But neither helps. How can I deploy my app to Openshift and have it pick up suitable Linux versions of all gems?

Answer (score 0):

Try including a full path to the file, like this: `rm $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/Gemfile.lock`

You should be able to connect to the server via `rhc ssh` in order to test the solution.